# Como mudar dados de uma tabela através de Migration?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql, migrations

Tenho uma tabela, que já tem alguns dados inputados. Uma dessas colunas recebia uma string que era setada na aplicação através de um ENUM, entretanto, o nome desses valores do ENUM foram alterados na API e agora preciso mudar todos os registros que tenham os nomes antigos para os novos nomes para não dar pau na hora de fazer o deploy da aplicação. Preciso realizar isso através de uma migration.
Saberiam me dizer como?

Mudar o valor de uma string da coluna em uma tabela para outra string através de migrations.

Answer (score -2):

1 - Crie uma nova migration usando o comando de criação de migração específico para o seu framework ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) ou banco de dados. Por exemplo, se estiver usando o Laravel, você pode usar o comando php artisan make:migration rename_enum_values.

2 - Na migration recém-criada, dentro do método up(), você precisará escrever o código para atualizar os registros na tabela.

- Recupere os registros da tabela usando o modelo correspondente ou diretamente através do Query Builder.
- Utilize as condições necessárias para selecionar apenas os registros que possuem os valores antigos a serem alterados.
- Atualize os valores para os novos nomes utilizando métodos ou consultas adequadas. Certifique-se de executar a mesma lógica de mapeamento usada na API.
  4 - Dentro do método down(), você pode escrever a lógica para reverter a mudança, caso necessário. Por exemplo, se os valores antigos foram alterados para os novos nomes, você pode reverter para os valores antigos novamente.

5 - Execute a migração no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento ou de produção usando o comando específico para o seu framework ORM ou banco de dados. Por exemplo, no Laravel, você pode executar php artisan migrate para aplicar todas as migrações pendentes.

É sempre importante fazer backup dos dados antes de executar qualquer migração, especialmente se você estiver alterando valores importantes na tabela.